# Loading data from webservices into table and then to Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services

Trying to load data from web services using web data connector into a table in NodeJS and then loading this table into DB. But there is code error stating
 Unchanged ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Tried to change the directory for require function dint help. But it works without using the web data connector provided by tableau.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "list"
});

//fs.readFile('list.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) 
                    {
if (err) throw err;
var obj = JSON.parse(tableData);
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var s_at = obj[i].id;
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO members (scraped_at) VALUES ('+s_at+');

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("x record inserted");
        });
    }
```

I need this code to load the id into a table in my database

Comment: At what line does the code raise an error?

Comment: How do you run your script? I mean `node some_file.js`? And where do you run this code? I mean, is it started on server or in browser?

Comment: @JeffMergler I get error in the first line. var mysql = require('mysql'); i.e. require is not defined. I.e Unchanged ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Comment: @Grynets I run this script in .js file and call it from a html file. This html file i am testing in a stimulator  (provided by the web data connector for tableau ). First i Downloaded the package  from http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/. and after editing one of the example files, earthqauake.js , i intiated the stimulator to check if i am able to load my  data in the tables in the UI of stimulator as a testing .It was working . But now  i am trying to connect directly to a database and load my data , for which i integregated the above code  with my main code .Now it is not working

Comment: >.js file and call it from a html file
You can't access node.js modules in browser, to use `require` you should run this code on server, not from `.html` file